# combobox vertical scrollbar width asp.net

Tags: asp.net, combobox, custom-controls

I want to increase the width of vertical scrollbar of the a ComboBox in Asp.Net 1.1 application.

Please note that I don't want to change the system settings that would increase the width of all the scrollbars.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add some **markup code**, furthermore I am not quite sure why you tagged your question with `custom-controls`. Try to be more specific in what you want to achieve, too.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET standard ComboBox (DropDownList) renders as a SELECT HTML element, which in browsers is rendered by OS and you have very little control over its appearance (besides some limited styling of colors and fonts).

You will have to use a custom control indeed if you wish to achieve that effect.